# How can I express 'teaching something to myself'?

Tags: verbs

I know the verb "to learn". I also know "self-learn" as a noun. But can it be used as a verb? Like

> I self-learnt something.

If not, how could I say I 'learnt' myself something in the past?

Comment: Notwithstanding the existing answers… This could be similar to the borrow/lend structure, the receiver & the giver. It would appear that in the self-education field, the giving is more emphasised than the receiving; hence self-taught over self-learned. I'm guessing it's a familiarity or idiom in usage rather than strictly correct or incorrect.

Comment: You could say you learned something **[autodidactically](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/autodidactic)**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We speak of **teach-yourself books and courses**.

In the past we would most likely say: **I'm self taught** or **I taught myself Russian** or **I learned it on my own**.

A more formal term is **autodidact** - a person who learns on his own, using **autodidactic** materials.

Comment: Can we say like: "I have learned French by myself" ?

Comment: Yes, you can, although it wouldn’t be my first choice.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a few people who say *I self-learned it*, but the typical idiomatic way of expressing the idea is to say "I am self-taught".

Answer (score 0):

There are verbs of this type, i.e. you can find them in written language,
e.g.

- to fine-tune, to force-feed geese, to peer-review a text, to speed-read, to test-drive

Such formations are mainly found in articles where specialists write about their special field of activity.  I think one should not exaggerate the use of these formations.

For "to self-learn" one might also say to learn without a teacher or to learn on one's own.